# Insert tag in HTML using shell script

Tags: html, shell

I have following HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
     <script src="../2.js"></script>
   </HEAD>
  <body>
    hello all!
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to insert `<script src="../blabla1.js"></script>` under `<head>` tag using a shell script. How can I do this?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: sed '<script src="../sc.js"></script> 4' test1.hml > test3.html ... But getting error "sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `<".. But again The line number to insert this tag is not fixed. I want to put the script line just after head.

Comment: sed  '/\<head\>/a \<script src="../blabla.js"\>\</script\>' test1.html ...... also not working.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do in this way:

```
sed  '/\<HEAD\>/a \<script src="../blabla.js"\>\</script\>' input.html > temp.html && mv temp.html input.html
```

Comment: Above command is inserting twice in HTML. How to overcome that?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, and doesn't add the tag twice:

```bash
sed '/<head>/a<script src="../blabla.js"></script>' index.html > temp.html && mv temp.html index.html
```

`\<HEAD\>` matches against the opening and closing tags

Take this example:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

`sed  '/\<head\>/a \<script src="../blabla.js"\>\</script\>'` makes it:

```
<html>
    <head>
<script src="../blabla.js"></script>
    </head>
<script src="../blabla.js"></script>
    <body>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Whereas `sed '/<head>/a<script src="../blabla.js"></script>'` makes it:

```
<html>
    <head>
<script src="../blabla.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks the same as the OP's answer. How does it avoid adding the tag twice? Am I missing something?

Comment: `\<HEAD\>` matches against the opening and closing tags